# HTML font size manipulation on uiWebview is failing for latest iOS update

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios10, font-size

I have been using this function for ages and no problem was faced, on the latest iOS update it stopped working, on execution the font size doesn't change.

What could be the reason and how could it be fixed?

```
 - (void)changeFontSize:(int)font {
      NSLog(@"changeFontSize %i", font);
      NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'", font];
      [readingWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];}
```

After further testing I have noticed that this problem only occurs on iPad iOS 10.1.1, but it works correctly on iPhone 10.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey this is a known issue and has an open radar [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/27201529) , but is reported to be fixed in iOS 10.2 beta 1 and in iOS 10.2 beta 2, so you will just have to wait, or you can try some of the solutions proposed on the radar, like enabling text auto resizing like so

```
[[[webView.scrollView.subviews.firstObject webView] preferences] _setTextAutosizingEnabled:YES];
```

hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you loads, saved my day.

Comment: I can't award the bounty until 4 hours, but as soon as it is made possible I will do so, I'm truly grateful.